# Need help in "jQuery closest" without parent or other selectors

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, when I applied jquery .css() method without using closest, it's working fine, but in case of closest same method is not working.

Please refer snippet:

```js
 //$('span').css("color","red");
$("body").delegate("button", "click", function () {
  $(this).closest('span').css("color","red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click to change color of span</button>
<span> Me Span here</span>
```

Comment: You made a typo. `button` has a `u` in it and only one `o`.

Comment: I corrected typo....but still not working...please check

Comment: `.closest()` looks for matching ancestor elements. Your `<span>` is not an ancestor of your `<button>`, but a sibling.

Answer (score 4):

1. Spell `button` correctly
2. `delegate` is deprecated. Don't use it. Use `on` instead.
3. `closest` searches the element's **ancestors**. The span you are looking for is not an ancestor, it is a sibling. Use `siblings`. You can also use `next()` if you have multiple buttons and spans all bundled together.

```js
$("body").on("click", "button", function () {
  $(this).siblings('span:first').css("color","red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click to change color of span</button>
<span> Me Span here</span>
```

Comment: `You can also use :first if you have multiple buttons and spans all bundled together.` In this case, I would recommend to use `.next()` instead

Comment: I upvoted but ...its not d solution to my query...what if in case of multiple spans as siblings ...I want to select d element span closest to button .....now trying by using element "Index" ...by checking which span has nearest value to my button.

Comment: What if in case of span added before my button.....its all dynamic ....so I can't rely on specific element selection.

Comment: @WC2 — It might be dynamic, but there needs to be some logic that you can implement in code. Start by identifying that logic. I'm not going to update this answer over and over every time you move the goalposts.

Comment: Hi ..... @Quentin ...I have built that logic....please check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/926052/

Answer (score 0):

Try this... `parent().find()`

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('span').css("color","red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click to change color of span</button>
<span> Me Span here</span>
```

Multiple span scenario

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('span:first').css("color","red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> Me Span here</span>
<button>Click to change color of span</button>

<p>
paragraph
</p>
<span> Me Span here</span>
```

Comment: What if I have multiple span inside my parent div....but I wanted only closest span to be changed...

Comment: use `find('span:first')`

Comment: No...if I add more spans before my button then ....using first I won't get closest to b changed.... by d way i have done it..check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/926052/